# Masking link in status bar works only until the 1st click

Tags: javascript, url, hide, anchor

This is the essence of my link:

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.ShowThis.com" onclick="javascript:this.href='go-here.php?resource=200401'">Visit ShowThis</a>
```

It works, but after the user clicks it the first time (which opens a new window with "go-here"), the link now shows "go-here" instead of "www.ShowThis.com".  What do I need to do to KEEP "www.ShowThis.com" as what is visible in the status bar?

Comment: Why do you need to mask `go-here.php`? Why are you trying to trick your users into going where they didn't expect?

Answer (score 0):

This way you won't be changing the href:

```
<a target="_blank" href="www.ShowThis.com" onclick="javascript:window.open('go-here.php?resource=200401');return false;">Visit ShowThis</a>
```